# Liquibase validation failed after modifying the entity

Tags: liquibase

I wanted to change the data type of one field from string to date. So i dropped the table in db. Then modified the liquibase file and ran the application. now it complains with the following message.

liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:

So after that I reverted the liquibase file changes and ran the application. This time no error but it is not creating the table.

Please help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the failed validation was an error about checksums. This happens when you modify a changeset which was already executed and try to execute it again.

Liquibase keeps all executed changesets in a table called `databasechangelog`, so it can find out which changesets can be skipped during execution.

To execute a changeset again, delete the corresponding from this table before, and run Liquibase again.

Answer (score 1):

When using Liquibase, you shouldn't (in general) modify the database outside of Liquibase - the main exception being if you are a developer working on your own private development database. If you are in that state (working on your own private database), then when you modify the database outside of Liquibase (i.e. dropping a table) you will also need to delete the row in the DATABASECHANGELOG table that corresponds to the table create statement so that when you re-run `liquibase update` it will re-create the table.